# How to point Angular static assets to WWW URL

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v7

When I run `ng build` I get this index.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ApiApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  const appData = JSON.parse('<%=json%>');
</script>

<app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Using a script after a build I will push the static assets to some CDN, so I actually want to generate an .html file that looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ApiApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  const appData = JSON.parse('<%=json%>');
</script>

<app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.github.com/runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.github.com/polyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.github.com/styles.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.github.com/vendor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.github.com/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

(I made up the domain `cdn.github.com`). So I could manually generate the urls for these files, but I am wondering if Angular allows us to configure it somehow?

Comment: Google for "angular cli cdn", click the second returned link, bingo: https://blog.chai-jay.com/angular-2-use-cdn-path-angular-cli-generated-index-html/

Comment: @JBNizet thanks I almost missed this comment, can you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure it in `angular.json` file in your angular project.

```
{
  "projects": {
    "<Your Angular Project Name>": {
        "architect": {
            "build": {
                "options": {
                    "baseHref": "/testapp/",
                    "deployUrl": "/testapp/",
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

`deployUrl` is basically what you are looking for.

For available build options and its description, you can refer to the below link:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

Comment: thanks, can you include a link to the docs for this? helps other ppl